# RedirectToAction stopped working when added a new route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I added the following route to the routing collection, then the call return `RedirectToAction("Index", "Company");` stopped working.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CompanyRoute",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Get" },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[a-z]+$" }

        );
```

And this error appears.

```
Error message: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Company]', but 
this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.Models.Company'.
```

Anyone know what this error can be about?

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with your route. That's a Razor error, and it means you've passed a type to your view that doesn't match the declared model for that view. In this case, you're passing a `List<Company>` instead of just `Company`. Check the action that renders this view and make sure the model you're passing into the `View()` call is a single `Company` instance.

Comment: When i remove the route the call to RedirectToAction works so it has to be the route.

Comment: Maybe another action is responding with the given route in place. That's kind of besides the point, though. I'm telling you what the error means. Find out why your view is being passed a `List<Company>` instead of just `Company` and the error will go away.

Comment: Yes the route (CompanyRoute) caught the call but could you explain to me why?, because if i write Company/Index in address field then the default route handles it. For some reason the call RedirectToAction("Index", "Company"); does not translate to Company/Index and therefore the route is redirecting to Company/Get with id set to null. What could it be that is causing this?

Comment: `{id}` doesn't necessarily mean it has to be an int. Defining the route like this essentially makes it a catch all, where going to a URL like `Company/Index`, hits the `Get` action with an id value of `"Company/Index"`. You need to move this route to the bottom of your route config so that it will only match if everything else falls through.